# Rxjs create timer in the subscribe handler?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have a subscription to an observable, and I'm trying to run a timer handler five seconds after the last emit value of the observable. The timer is then reset on the next emit

```
// If the service does not emit for 5 second, the timeout handler is called, 
// then the timer begins again on the next service emit
service.on('update')
            .subscribe((event) => {                
                this.updateCounter(event);
                // Clear previous timer
                this.timerSub && this.timerSub.unsubscribe()
                // Create new timer
                this.timerSub = timer(5000)
                    .subscribe( () => {
                        this.timerHandler();
                    });
            });

....
timerHandler() {
   // do something
}
```

This works ok, but I'm wondering if there's a way of doing this that is more in line with Rxjs patterns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an easy task for `switchMap()`:

```
service.on('update')
  .pipe(
    tap(() => this.updateCounter(event)),
    switchMap(() => timer(5000)),
  )
  .subscribe(() => this.timerHandler());
```

Answer (score 0):

What not:

```
const events$ = service.on('update');
events$.subscribe(this.updateCounter);
events$.delay(5000).subscribe(timerHandler);
```

Comment: Hi. Would that delay() cancel the previous delay e.g. like a debounce?

Comment: No. If this is what you need you should consider using debounce. The down side is that it can lead to "starvation" so you should mix debounce and timeout to make sure you do update eventually